# Summing the results of Case queries in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I think this is a relatively straightforward question but I have spent the afternoon looking for an answer and cannot yet find it. So...

I have a view with a country column and a number column. I want to make any number less than 10 'other' and then sum the 'other's into one value.

For example,

```
AR  10
AT  7
AU  11
BB  2
BE  23
BY  1
CL  2
```

I used CASE as follows:

```
select country = case
when number < 10 then 'Other'
else country
end,
number
from ...
```

This replaces the countries values with less than 10 in the number column to other but I can't work out how to sum them. I want to end up with a table/view which looks like this:

```
AR  10
AU  11
BE  23
Other  12
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it into a derived table to avoid repeating the CASE statement.

```
select country, 
       sum(number) as number
from (
    select case
              when number < 10 then 'Other'
              else country
           end as country,
           number
    from ...
) t
group by country
```

Answer (score 3):

Just group by your case statement:

```
select 
  country = case
     when number < 10 then 'Other'
     else country
  end,
  sum(number)
from ...
group by
  case
     when number < 10 then 'Other'
     else country
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select country, number
from your_table
where number >= 10
union
select 'Other' as country, sum(number)
from your_table
where number < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Group by

```
 select country = case
    when number < 10 then 'Other'
    else country
    end,
    sum(number)
    from ...
    group by 
       case when number < 10 then 'Other' else country end
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close... You just can't do country = case...   Try

```
Select
      Case when number < 10 then 'Other'
           Else country end  as finalcountry,
      Sum(number) as total number
   From
      YourTable
   Group by
      Finalcountry
```

Since I don't have MySQL handy, I don't remember if it allows you to use the final column name as a group by... You may have to re-copy the case when clause into the group by clause too.